# Debian sound on hdmi instead of jack

Tags: audio, debian, hdmi

I installed debian (gnome) and i can't get my sound working.
When i use inxi -A i get the following result:

```
Audio:     Card-1: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Cayman/Antilles HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6900 Series] driver: snd_hda_intel
           Card-2: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA) driver: snd_hda_intel
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture ver: 1.0.24
```

My feeling tells me my sound output is on the HDMI instead of my jackplug on my motherboard.

How can i change this to my motherboard sound output?

Answer (score 3):

You probably are using pulseaudio. Launch pavucontrol (from package of the same name) to see if pulseaudio is correctly configured:

- in the 5th tab (Configuration) look at the status of the several device you have. Their you will be able to configure your hdmi device
- in the third tab (Output device) you can then click on the green icon with check sign to set the default pulseaudio output.

For application not speaking pulseaudio, you can create a $HOME/.asoundrc file with

```
pcm.!default {
     type pulse
}

ctl.!default {
     type pulse
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, meanwhile with the help of some friends i got it tow work. Only 1 problem left now. Flashplugin doesn't give sound. (for example youtube when not using html5 or the settlers online browser game) when i look in pavucontrol, it wont appear, tho the other browserstreams will.  Any ideas?

Comment: I belive the problem is that flash speak only to alsa. See my edit for a full answer.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the help again, but does not work yet :(

Comment: while playing something with flash, try to use pavucontrol to see if the sound it there.

Comment: Nope tried that already, the stream doesnt show up. Others i get from iceweasel do (for example youtube video on html5 instead of flash). But well, i guess i need to get a 5.1 soundcard anyway, i miss my surroundsound (new motherboard seemed to have only stereo out) Thanks for the help anyway